# Scraping with selenium where table has same class names

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to parse the table using selenium and beautiful soup and I have issues locating and atracting value from the class. It appears that each column has same class name which makes it more difficult. Here is the  part of the  html code `m trying to parse:

[image]

And here is how the table look:

[image]

So what I coded so far is this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(base_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("plp-pod__image")[0].click()
first = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label")[0].getText()
first
```

So basically i open the Chrom browser, load the page of the item i am looking and than looking for all classes called "col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label" and trying to get the text out of the first one that appears. I am trying to solve this for all 5 dimensions and its values.

When i execute my code I get this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-27-2e124acf6be5> in <module>
      3 driver.implicitly_wait(100)
      4 driver.find_elements_by_class_name("plp-pod__image")[0].click()
----> 5 first = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label")[0].getText()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any idea how do I parse these elements to get all 5 of dimensions and its values into pandas dataframe?

I tried combining both of your suggestions like this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, 
NoSuchFrameException
i = "Marshalltown PT164BR"
base_url = f"https://www.homedepot.com/s/" + i +"?NCNI-5"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(base_url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
".plp-pod__image"))).click()
#%%

groups = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("specs__group")
data = {}
for group in groups:
    if "placeholder" not in group.get_attribute("class"):
        specs = group.find_elements_by_class_name("specs__cell")
        dimension = specs[0].text.strip()
        value = float(specs[1].text.replace("in","").strip())
        #print(dimension,":",value)
        if dimension not in data:
            data[dimension] = []
        data[dimension].append(value)
print(data)
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(data_frame)
```

and I get to the web page I am using as a test, to the item I am using as a test, but it does not seems to read the correct classes and it gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-1f3f99bc45ee> in <module>
      5         specs = group.find_elements_by_class_name("specs__cell")
      6         dimension = specs[0].text.strip()
----> 7         value = float(specs[1].text.replace("in","").strip())
      8         #print(dimension,":",value)
      9         if dimension not in data:

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code which will fetch the Dimensions of the product.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
i = "Marshalltown PT164BR"
base_url ="https://www.homedepot.com/s/" + i +"?NCNI-5"
driver.get(base_url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".plp-pod__image"))).click()
Dimensions_Type=[]
Dimention_Size=[]
elements=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "(//h4[text()='Dimensions']/following::div[contains(@class,'specs__table')])[1]/div")))
for ele in elements:
  if "placeholder" not in ele.get_attribute("class"):
     DimensionsType=ele.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label']").get_attribute("textContent")
     DimentionSize=ele.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label']/following-sibling::div[1]").get_attribute("textContent")
     Dimensions_Type.append(DimensionsType)
     Dimention_Size.append(DimentionSize)

df=pd.DataFrame({"DimensionSize":Dimention_Size,"DimensionType":Dimensions_Type})
print(df)
```

**Output on console:**

```
    DimensionSize       DimensionType
0         16 in    Blade Length (in.)
1           4.5     Blade Width (in.)
2       3.63 in  Product Height (in.)
3         16 in  Product Length (in.)
4        4.5 in   Product Width (in.)
```

Comment: Excellent Kunduk. This is the one. Thank you so much. I understand every line of code this is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous post, if i use this HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="specs__group col-12 col-lg-6" style="min-height: 39px;">
    <div class="col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label">Blade Length (in.)</div>
    <div class="col-6 specs__cell">16 in</div>
</div>
<div class="specs__group col-12 col-lg-6" style="min-height: 39px;">
    <div class="col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label">Blade Width (in.)</div>
    <div class="col-6 specs__cell">4.5</div>
</div>
<div class="specs__group col-12 col-lg-6" style="min-height: 39px;">
    <div class="col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label">Product Height (in.)</div>
    <div class="col-6 specs__cell">3.63 in</div>
</div>
<div class="specs__group col-12 col-lg-6" style="min-height: 39px;">
    <div class="col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label">Product Length (in.)</div>
    <div class="col-6 specs__cell">16 in</div>
</div>
<div class="specs__group col-12 col-lg-6" style="min-height: 39px;">
    <div class="col-6 specs__cell specs__cell--label">Product Width (in.)</div>
    <div class="col-6 specs__cell">4.5 in</div>
<div class="specs__group placeholder" style="min-height: 39px;">
    ??
</div>
</body>
```

You can create an dict or dataframe:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, NoSuchFrameException

base_url = "file:///C:/Users/.../blade.html"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(base_url)
groups = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("specs__group")
data = {}
for group in groups:
    if "placeholder" not in group.get_attribute("class"):
        specs = group.find_elements_by_class_name("specs__cell")
        dimension = specs[0].text.strip()
        value = float(specs[1].text.replace("in","").strip())
        #print(dimension,":",value)
        if dimension not in data:
            data[dimension] = []
        data[dimension].append(value)
print(data)
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(data_frame)
```

Comment: i think this solution is exactly what i need. I so when i get to the load the page and it continues with the rest of your code this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float. Any idea why would that happen?

Comment: I added my example with your code as well in my original post.

Comment: text_value = specs[1].text.replace("in","").strip() 
print(text_value) The output you want should be an number, but you get an string like "Steel", because the 
table "Details" on the site has too the class name specs__group. Check with len(groups), you want around 5 and get 22.

Iterate your path to the Table "Dimensions" like: id specsContainer > class specs__table[0] ...
Test if you get what you want via ouput to the console.